# Extração HTML+ PHP para EXCEL numeros grandes com a formatação errada

Tags: php, html5, microsoft-excel

Tenho um sistema web que faz conversão de uma tabela `HTML` para o EXCEL, contudo tem um campo correspondendo ao CNPJ , quando transformo essa tabela para EXCEL, ela me retornar com `1,111111+14` ao invés de `111111111111111`.

Como posso deixar formatado corretamente ao passar pro EXCEL ?

```html
<?php
       $file = 'planilha.xls';
       header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
       header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$file}\"" );
       header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );
    ?>
    <?php 
    session_start();
                $serverName = "NOME_BANCO";
                $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"NOME", "UID"=>"USUARIO", "PWD"=>"SENHA" );
                $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
                     if ($conn === false) {
                      die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

     $data_inicial = $_POST['data_inicio'];
     $data_final = $_POST['data_final'];

     $query = ("SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE EMISSAO BETWEEN '$data_inicial' AND '$data_final' ORDER BY EMISSAO");
     $params = array(); 
     $options = array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
     $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, $options);

    ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="pt-br">

        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        </head>

        <body>

            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <center><b>CNPJ</b></center>
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php while ($campo= sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
     ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                <?php echo $campo['CNPJ']; ?>
                            </center>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <?php
            }
        ?>
            </table>
            <?php include("rodape.php")?>
```

Comment: Direto do HTML creio que não tem como. Mas você pode fazer um código VBA de menos de 5 linhas que vai aplicar a formatação correta à coluna, por exemplo.

Comment: Você está dizendo no cabeçalho que é uma planilha Excel mas está retornando um HTML. Essa é uma gambiarra que pode até funcionar, mas vai chegar em um ponto que não vai ter escapatória, você vai ter que gerar um arquivo Excel de verdade (aparentemente você chegou nesse ponto).  Arquivos `.xlsx` são arquivo `.zip` com arquivos `.xml` e outros arquivos diversos. Esta estrutura segue um padrão chamado [OfficeOpenXML](http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML-xlsx.php) e adotado como padrão [ECMA 376](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm)

Comment: Para ter controle sobre formatação de dados, negrito, largura de colunas, etc.. você precisa criar este arquivo corretamente. Você vai precisar encontrar uma biblioteca em PHP que crie esse padrão de arquivos, ler sua documentação e utilizá-la corretamente.